# iOS 8.2 [peripheral discoverServices:] not calling to diddiscoverservices

Tags: ios, xcode, cbperipheral

I have update my iphone to iOS 8.2 and now one of my projects is not working because when I call to discover services, `cbperipheral` is not calling to `diddiscoverservices` function.

I am connected to the bluetooth but when i do:

```
[peripheral discoverServices:nil];
```

I don't receive anything in:

```
- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)periph didDiscoverServices:(NSError *)error
```

It works perfectly in iOS 8.1.

Does anybody know if is an iOS bug, or if i have to change something in my project to work fine `CoreBluetooth`?

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue with 8.2.  Came here to ask the same question.  On 8.1, all the devices I try work just fine.  On 8.2, some devices  connect just fine - in my case, a Bluetooth LE Thermometer fails.  Just submitted a bug report to Apple.  I'll update if I hear anything back.

Comment: Similar issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29049260/ios-bluetooth-not-discovering-peripheral-services-sometimes

Comment: @adamup I have same issue. Did you able to solve this issue?