# IOS Bluetooth not discovering peripheral services. (sometimes!)

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth

Sometimes, my app will connect to the peripheral device (i.e. "didConnectPeripheral" is called) but it will not discover available services ("didDiscoverServices" is not called). Also when this happens the peripheral (an Adafruit Bluefruit based on the nRF8001) will say its not connected! This only happens about 1/5 of the times the app is launched.

The blocks of code below are always executed:

```
func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager!, didDiscoverPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral!, advertisementData: [NSObject : AnyObject]!, RSSI: NSNumber!) {
     //Connect to the peripheral if its a UART
    if(peripheral.name == "UART") {
        currentPeripheral = peripheral
        currentPeripheral.delegate = self
        central.connectPeripheral(currentPeripheral, options: nil) 
    }
}


 func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager!, didConnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral!) {
    println()
    println("Connected to: \(peripheral.name)")
    peripheral.discoverServices(nil)
    connectionStatus = .Connected
    central.stopScan()
    println("***Stopped scanning***")
}
```

Any idea why "didDiscoverServices" is not called?

(I am running the app on an IPod touch 5th gen)

Comment: Do you keep reference of `peripheral`?

Comment: If you do `currentPeripheral.discoverServices(nil)` instead of `peripheral.discoverServices(nil)`?

Comment: Yes I keep a reference to peripheral once its discovered. (I edited my post)

Comment: I did `currentPeripheral.discoverServices(nil)` the result is the same.

Comment: Did you solve this somehow? I am currently facing similar problem. iOS says it is connected, and fails to discover services, while the peripheral claims no connection attempts were received. Tested both in our app and using nRF Connect. Both exhibit the same behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [CoreBluetooth programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/PerformingCommonCentralRoleTasks/PerformingCommonCentralRoleTasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH3-SW1), you should do this:

> Before you begin interacting with the peripheral, you should set the
>   peripheral’s delegate to ensure that it receives the appropriate
>   callbacks, like this:

```
peripheral.delegate = self;
```

Therefore, your didConnectPeripheral function should look something like this:

```
func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager!, didConnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral!) {
        NSLog("peripheral connected")
        peripheral.delegate = self
        peripheral.discoverServices(nil)

    }
```